# Image id not sent to server,if image is used as button

Tags: php

I'm trying to send the  id of an image to the server which is used as 
 image  button Here, but every time wrong id is sent to the 
server's database. Irrespective of the image chosen ,alert box is 
always displaying the same message.

```
// file named as  garbage.php
<form>
<input type="hidden"  name="sub1" id="sub1" value="<?php echo "$merge1";?>">
<input type="image" src="survey_photos/<?php echo "$merge1.jpg";?>"
 alt="<?    php echo "$merge1";?>"  style="width:230px;height:300px">
<input type="hidden"  name="sub2" id="sub2" 
value="<?php echo "$merge2";?    >"/>
<input type="image" src="survey_photos/<?php echo "$merge2.jpg";?>" 
alt="<?  php echo "$merge2";?>"  style="width:230px;height:300px">
</form>
//*server script* sending either image1 or image2
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sub1']))
{
if(mysqli_query($link1,"insert into result values('$user','$merge1','$sid',NOW())"))
{
echo '<script>alert(" submitted 1");window.location.href="garbage.php"    </script>';

}
else
{
echo '<script>alert(" not submitted 1");window.location.href="garbage.php"   </script>';

}
}
else if(isset($_GET['sub2']))
{
    echo "varsha";
    if(mysqli_query($link1,
"insert into result    values('$user','$merge2','$sid',NOW())"))
echo '<script>alert("submitted 2");window.location.href="garbage.php"</script>';
else
echo '<script>alert("not submitted 2");window.location.href="garbage.php"</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: There's no value set for your two images, no name and echo "$merge2.jpg"; should be echo $merge2 . "jpg"; if i'm not wrong

Comment: Side-remark: In PHP, you can redirect using [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) as shown in the link's first example. No need to use `<script>` tag as you have done.

Comment: Through some sources i come to know that ,using image button we can't sent data to server .That's why have used hidden type along with image button and not specified  name or id with image button. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Should i use name  with image button or there is some other way to remove the error.